# Android studio got stuck at creating flutter project

Tags: flutter

After upgrading my flutter, when i try to create a new flutter project it get stuck showing creating flutter project for hours without any change And when i run flutter doctor -v, i have no issues.

```
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\USER\Documents\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.60.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.107

• No issues found!
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try these following(one by one):

1. Reinstall Flutter plugin.
2. Reinstall flutter SDK.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).